# I want to restrict the number of records fetched from my MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-integration

```
This is the inbound channel adapter which fetches the matching criteria records
from the DB:

<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    <int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter
      id="simpleInboundAdapter" channel="pollingInputChannel"
      query="{$or:[{'status':'New'},{$and:[{'status':'Failure'},{'noOfRetries':{$lt:3}}]}]}"
      collection-name="custommessages" entity-class="com.att.ssp.deviceeventprocessor.model.CustomMessage"
      mongodb-factory="mongoDbFactory">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="30000" max-messages-per-poll="1">
            <!-- <int:transactional synchronization-factory="txSyncFactory" /> -->
        </int:poller>
    </int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter>


My use case is that I need to restrict the number of records fetched.  
Say I have 100 records matching the criteria but I want only 10 records to be fetched. Can any one help me how to achieve that functionality here.
```

I even tried with this exmaple but still none of the record has been fetched here can any one really help please was struggling the whole day for this.Any helping hands please..

```
<int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="simpleInboundAdapter" channel="pollingInputChannel"
        query-expression="new BasicQuery('{''status'' : ''New''}').limit(2)"
        collection-name="custommessages" entity-class="com.att.ssp.deviceeventprocessor.model.CustomMessage"
        mongodb-factory="mongoDbFactory">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="30000" max-messages-per-poll="1">
            <!-- <int:transactional synchronization-factory="txSyncFactory" /> -->
            </int:poller>
    </int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

is this the wrong approch to filter reocords form mongo inbound adapter..
or what will be the ideal way to filter record count.

Comment: use $limit operator

Comment: Hi felix thanks for the reply where can i use $limit..can u please suggest ,as am new to spring intergration..

Comment: @felix You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$limit` is part of [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) and since `<int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter` is based on the `find()` we can't use that `$limit`.

We possible here is only `limit()` from [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/).

Such a functionality is available since Spring Integration `4.3.6`:

```
query-expression="new BasicQuery('{$or:[{''status'':''New''},{$and:[{''status'':''Failure''},{''noOfRetries'':{$lt:3}}]}]}').limit(100)"
```

Comment: Hi Artem i have tired this approch but still it is not working.

Comment: OK! Update your question with particular info and results of the execution.

Comment: Sorry Artem the syntax u have posted is working fine for spring intergration jar 4.3.8.So i was using old version of spring integration jar becuase of that it was not working thank you for posting..:)